# Why do my Client Hyper-V connections keep dying?

Tags: networking, windows-8, internet-connection, hyper-v

I have Client Hyper-V on Win8, hosting a few VMs like ubuntu, a clean windows build-machine, etc. My VMs are connected to an external virtual-switch (shared with the management OS), and that works fine... for a while - they can see the world. However, after an indeterminate time, when I resume the guest VM it won't have internet access. It simply can't see out. Shutting down the guest completely and restarting it doesn't help.

Currently, the only way I can "cure" this is to suspend the guests, go into Virtual Switch Manager, remove my virtual-switches, re-add *the same* virtual-switches, and reactivate the guest OS. Then it immediately works. This even works if the guest was just paused (not fully shut down).

Is this a common fault? What can I do to prevent this?

Update: after experimentation, it seems I only need to delete / re-add the *external* virtual-switch. Until then, the guest OS thinks it is disconnected.

Comment: **when I resume the guest VM it won't have internet access.** means if you don't pause the VM then your internet access continue without any interruption?

Comment: @avirk it may also relate to suspend/resume at the host - lots of variables. But to answer your question - it doesn't seem to happen when using the guest continuously... But I rarely need to use the guest continuously :)

Comment: I wonder if this is due to the fact that Hyper-V Client is a ported version of the Hyper-V server, and thus expected to operate with client constantly running most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here was (as harrymc rightly noted) dodgy drivers and/or hardware, in this case an on-board Marvell network adapter. It was not possible to follow the "use an older driver" approach (it simply doesn't install, and I'm not sure that is a great practice anyway), so I instead threw in an Intel CT network adapter (or a GT would probably be fine, if you lack a spare PCI Express slot).

With the on-board, this scenario would happen when suspending the host: it simply doesn't resume correctly as far as Hyper-V is concerned. With the dedicated NIC - it *just works*. If you are going to the trouble of replacing the NIC, you might as well get a well supported model / brand, hence why I went for the Intel.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a driver issue.

For example, in the thread [Hyper-V Virtual Switch (Windows 8)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/W8ITProPreRel/thread/480e6460-17c8-4b44-9ca1-d7f185ad8601/)
the solution was to downgrade to Windows 7 drivers, rather than using the ones that windows 8 installed.

Comment: any idea whether it is talking about the host or the guest?

Comment: Windows 8 is supposedly the host.

Comment: in my case I also have win8 guests - you can see how it may become confusing ;p

Comment: As the problem also arrives with linux, the host must be the common factor. Best to continue testing with linux clients at first if possible.

Comment: For info, I've added a separate answer with more info, but you definitely deserve the bounty for leading me down the right road - cheers.